# Xamarin.Plugins.Messaging unable to send email with attachment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using the `Xamarin.Plugins.Messaging` nuget to try and send an email with an attachment.  I'm getting the error

> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com./files/Summary.pdf

I've set up the Android manifest according to the instructions

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap" android:label="<MyAppName>">
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="com.<MyAppName>.fileprovider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

and added the `file_paths.xml` file set to Android Resource

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Here is the code I'm using to save a byte array as a file and attach it to an email

```
 var fileResult = await dal.getdoc(id); //REST call
 File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "BuyerSummary.pdf"), fileResult);
 string fileName = Path.Combine(Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "BuyerSummary.pdf");

   var email = new EmailMessageBuilder()

              .Subject("Buyer Netsheet summary")
              .Body(textSummary)
              .WithAttachment(fileName, "application/pdf")
              .Build();

            emailMessenger.SendEmail(email);
```

Comment: Did you check the file exists in the folder /data/data/com./files/Summary.pdf  using File.Exists(path) ?

Comment: Your error log is displayed "Summary.pdf" , but in your code the file name is "BuyerSummary.pdf" .

Comment: That's a typo when posting the question.   The file names are the same

Comment: Also, I checked and file exits is true. thanks

Comment: Ok, I solved this mostly now, using  <cache-path name="cache" path="/" /> in the file_paths.xml file together with    var folder = Xamarin.Essentials.FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(folder, "BuyerSummary.pdf"), fileResult);
                string fileName = Path.Combine(folder, "BuyerSummary.pdf");

Comment: Now I'm able to attach it but the file is corrupted when trying to read it.  Maybe I'm not writing the file correctly